# How does the Net::SSH2 module know the other side of the connection is finished sending data?

Tags: perl, libssh2

I've been using the SSH2 module for a while and have found it to work quite well. The part I always find difficult is telling when the returned data has complete. For example, this piece of code I find all over the internet

```
my $ssh2 = new Net::SSH2();
$ssh2->connect('127.0.0.1') or die $!;
$ssh2->auth_password('bob', 'smith');
if(!$ssh2->auth_ok()) { die $!; }
my $channel = $ssh2->channel();
$channel->shell();
print $channel "ls -l\n";
while(<$channel>)
{
  print $_;
}
```

It appears that this "knows" when the end of the stream has been reached because it returns immediately once the last line is returned. What I want to know is how does it know the data has finished? The prompt is not returned so I'm guessing it looks for the prompt. What happens if something else returns a string that looks like the prompt? Will it stop?

Comment: Do robots dream of electric sheep?

Comment: Only if you put a `Sleep` call in your code.

Comment: There is no prompt. It knows because the remote applications has exited. When the program exits, it closes it's file descriptors.

Comment: @jordanm. Can you elaborate on that? Which program has exited? ls? How does it know from this end that it has exited?

Comment: I don't think it is using the system prompt to detect end of data. System prompts are not standardized.  The prompt on most unix-like systems is configurable even by each user (in a file like .bashrc or .login).

Comment: @Paul. That makes sense however maybe it is part of the SSH standard that some sort of ending char sequence can be set once connected? It must know the end of stream has been reached somehow.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: Paul, are you saying the remote system sends a ctrl-D?

Comment: It sends an "EOF". Saying more would be speculation on my part.

Comment: @Paul. I have found that if you do exec("ls") then you get notification when ls has finished because the channel has closed. But my question is about shell where the channel stays open to execute multiple commands. I'm not sure if there is any notification when using shell.

Comment: @MikeKulls Some pipes have a line buffered mode where the receiver can indicate they wish to block until a new line is received. Effectively that is what the while < $channel > loop is doing. Anyway, maybe you should experiment with multiple commands, see what happens, and ask a question about that if it doesn't work or is acting strange.  The code with your current question only transmits  one command.  I would think duplicating the print channel and while channel portions with another command would be a good experiment.